# Custom NoInternet In Andriod Studio But image and layout not scale to fit

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used this code to make custom No internet dialog but when i successfully build then the problem is half screen show my custom image but half show the no connection error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j41Jf.jpg)

In Activity_main.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24iec.jpg)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:progress="20"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splashloading01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash_loading"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </ImageView>



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        </WebView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/internet"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/noConnectionLogo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
              <Button
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:text="Join"
                android:id="@+id/btnNoConnection">

              </Button>



        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity.xml my code is

```
package www.foodmartshop.com;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Button btnNoInternetConnection;
    ProgressBar progressBarWeb;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        //Button No Internet//
        btnNoInternetConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNoConnection);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); //No Internet//
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        progressBarWeb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

        //Swipe//
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();
            }
        }); //Swipe//
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmartshop.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new www.foodmartshop.MyAppWebViewClient() {


            //Hide The Loading Page
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.splashloading01).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }


        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBarWeb.setProgress(newProgress);

                if (newProgress == 100) {

                    progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    }

    public void checkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isConnected()) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        else if (mobileNetwork.isConnected()){
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

        else{
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


}
```

In Mamifest my code is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="www.foodmartshop.com">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Plz help me i didnt understand the problem

Comment: what you want to do, also explain

Comment: Separate your webview from custom no connection so when internet is established your webview does what it's required to do and when Internet is not you pass intent to the the custom no connection layout

Answer (score 0):

try this---->

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hdyt);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    //Button No Internet//
    btnNoInternetConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNoConnection);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); //No Internet//
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progressBarWeb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
    checkConnection();
  //  mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmartshop.com");

    //Swipe//
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            checkConnection();
            mWebView.reload();

        }
    }); //Swipe//
  //  mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmartshop.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {


        //Hide The Loading Page
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.splashloading01).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }


    });

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
     checkConnection();
            progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBarWeb.setProgress(newProgress);

            if (newProgress == 100) {

                progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else
            {
                checkConnection();
            }

            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

}

public void checkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (!wifi.isConnected()) {
    progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (!mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        progressBarWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.foodmartshop.com");

        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

### later you must be noticing progressbar loads continuously even if internet is not there then you must use this-->

*just an example* -->

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progressDialog.hide();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```